# what the central limit theorem says

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Asked what the central limit theorem says, a student replies, "as you take larger
and larger samples from a population, the histogram of the sample values looks more and
more Normal". Is the student right? Explain your answer.

My answer is no, the student is wrong. My explanation is the histogram of the sample values will look like the population distribution, whatever it might happen to be. The central limit theorem says that the histogram of sample means (from many large samples) will look more and more Normal.

Am I right about it? It is that simple? Is there anything more I can say about this?

Comment: You are certainly absolutely right about the histogram of sample values.

Comment: am I right about the following part: The central limit theorem says that the histogram of sample means (from many large samples) will look more and more Normal?

Comment: The CLT of course does not hold for all distributions. And "look more and more normal" is vague, as is '"many large samples." The answer by Batman (scaling) is much more precise.

Comment: What distribution does CLT apply and what is a better way to phase look more and more normal?

Comment: CLT applies to any distribution whose variance exists, and to many more. For statement, I guess I am being fussy, but I would state the result exactly (see e.g. the Wikipedia article on CLT).

Comment: when I think more about it, I change my wording a little bit: the histogram of the sample values will look like the standard normal distribution, is this the same thing as I write above before or is this right also?

Comment: Thee seems to have been no change of wording in the post. As you pointed out, the histogram of sample values will in general not look more and more normal. For example, the histogram of sample values for an exponential will look more and more like $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$. As far as CLT goes, if we take a large number of $m$ of samples of size $n$ from a "nice" distribution, calculate the sample means, and normalize them by multiplying by $\sqrt{n}$, then as $n, m$ get large, the histogram will look more and more like a normal with variance $1$.

Comment: I am wondering standard normal distribution is not the same as probability distribution right

Comment: You are right. There are many many distributions, the normal family is just one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps:

Take an appropriate random variable (finite second moment). Let's say that $\frac{S_n}{n}$ is the empirical mean of the random variable, and $\mu$ the theoretical mean. In this setting, $$\displaystyle \frac{S_n}{n} - \mu$$ is the *deviation* of the empirical mean from the theoretical one.

What the CLT says is: with an appropriate scaling, the deviations are normally distributed, i.e.

$$\mathbb P\left( \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}\left(\frac{S_n}{n} - \mu\right) \leq x \right) \to \phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^x \exp(-\frac{y^2}{2}) dy.$$

Quoting Frank den Hollander (*Large Deviations*, AMS): "CLT quantifies the probability that $S_n$ differs from $\mu n$ by an amount of order $\sqrt{n}$. Deviations of this size are called "normal". [...] [Deviations of size $n$] are called "large"."

An equivalent formulation of the result above is:
$$\frac{S_n}{n} \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n}),$$
so, I would say that you are right.

Comment: when I think more about it, I change my wording a little bit: the histogram of the sample values will look like the standard normal distribution, is this the same thing as I write above before or is this right also?

Comment: The histogram of the means (each mean from a certain sample) will look like a normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2/n$, more and more as the size of the samples goes to infinity.

Comment: As you said before, the (frequency) histogram of the values (of a specific sample) will always reflect the probability distribution of the random variable.

Comment: I am wondering standard normal distribution is not the same as probability distribution right

Comment: Standard normal distribution is the probability distribution of a normal with mean zero and variance 1.

Comment: So my original claim should work better listed here "the histogram of the sample values will look like the population distribution, whatever it might happen to be" since this applies to all distribution, right?

Comment: put everything together: the histogram of the sample values will look like the population distribution, whatever that distribution  might look like as the sample size increases.  The CLT says the sample mean follows a normal distribution with mean u and variance $\sigma^2 /n$ as the sample size goes to infinity. But CLT fails to population that has fat tails such as Cauchy Distribtion. Is this right? If so, do you think I could add a little more?

Answer (score 0):

You're not necessarily right about the histograms. Take i.i.d. samples of a Cauchy distribution - what happens?

You need at least square integrable random variables for versions CLT to apply.

Central limit theorems roughly state that if you scale the sample mean's deviations from the true mean by an appropriate factor ($\sqrt{n}$ where $n$ is the sample size in the classical CLT), you get convergence in distribution to a normal distribution.

Comment: "My explanation is the histogram of the sample values will look like the population distribution, whatever it might happen to be"...is right?

Comment: The sample value part is fine (you can justify that by the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem). The histogram of the sample means on the other hand is where the problem can occur.

Comment: when I think more about it, I change my wording a little bit: the histogram of the sample values will look like the standard normal distribution, is this the same thing as I write above before or is this right also?

Comment: So my original claim should work better listed here "the histogram of the sample values will look like the population distribution, whatever it might happen to be" since this applies to all distribution, right?

Comment: put everything together: the histogram of the sample values will look like the population distribution, whatever that distribution  might look like as the sample size increases.  The CLT says the sample mean follows a normal distribution with mean u and variance $\sigma^2 /n$ as the sample size goes to infinity. But CLT fails to population that has fat tails such as Cauchy Distribtion. Is this right? If so, do you think I could add a little more?